# Notation in rate distortion theory (vector quantization)

Tags: probability, statistics, notation, information-theory, coding-theory

I have been reading whatever sources I could get my hands on today, regarding this problem. 
Most notes online about rate distortion theory come from the book *Elements of Information Theory* by Thomas M. Cover and Joy A. Thomas. The book seems well regarded so  I assume i am misunderstanding something.

I.e the following [slides](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~yxie77/ece587/Lecture20.pdf). I am confused by the notation - which comes from the book. If we look at slides 14 and 16 in the slides deck linked. Firstly on slide 14 they denote a sequence of random variables (i.e a sequence of bits, as far as I understand) as $X^n$ 
$$
X^n = (X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}), \quad X_{n} \sim p(x)
$$
and the codeword for that sequence as $\hat{X}^n$.  Now moving on to slide 16 they seem to mix between $X^n$ and $x^n$ i.e they mention that the distortion between sequences 
$$
d\left(x^{n}, \hat{x}^{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} d\left(x_{i}, \hat{x}_{i}\right)
$$

And distortion for a $\left(2^{n R}, n\right)$ code: 
$$
D=E d\left(X^{n}, g_{n}\left(f_{n}\left(X^{n}\right)\right)\right)=\sum_{x^{n}} p\left(x^{n}\right) d\left(x^{n}, g_{n}\left(f_{n}\left(x^{n}\right)\right)\right)
$$

but as far as i can tell they are the same thing? What is the idea behind this, if any? Am  missing something. This notation is consistent across all sources I could find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X$ is a random variable whilst $x$ is an observation. In the same way, $X^n$ is a joint random variable that consists of $n$ i.i.d random variables whilst $x^n$ is an observation (or realisation) of the random variable $X^n$.

For instance, let $X$ be a random variable that represents a coin toss (you can for instance assume heads = $1$ and tails = $0$). In this case $X \sim \text{Bern}(1/2)$. If you observe $n$ iid variables as the same time then you have the random variable $X^n$. If you sample $X^n$ then you get a $n$ -bit vector which is denoted as $x^n$. In our example, there would be $2^n$ different values that $x^n$ can take.

So $X^n$ is the joint random variable $(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$ whilst $x^n = x_1x_2...x_n$ is a realisation.

Let $x^n$ and $\hat{x}^n$ be two different $n$-bit vectors, where  $\hat{x}^n = \phi(x^n) $ for some arbitrary function $\phi(\cdot)$, then the distortion due to the application of $\phi(\cdot)$ is $d(x^n, \phi(x^n)) = d(x^n, \hat{x}^n)$, where $d$ is some chosen distortion function.

If each $x_i$ is independent then $d(x^n, \hat{x}^n) = \sum _{i} d(x_i, \hat{x}_i)$ where the distortion in this case will be the distortion per $n$ bits. If the distortion needs to be calculated on a 'per bit' basis then you can just divide by $n$, i.e. $d(x^n, \hat{x}^n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum _i d(x_i, \hat{x}_i)$.

If we want to find the expected distortion caused by the application of $\phi(\cdot)$ to $X^n$ then we can compute

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[d(X^n , \phi(X^n)] = \sum_{x^n \in \mathcal{X}^n} p({x^n}) d(x^n , \phi(x^n))
\end{align}

$\mathcal{X}^n$ is the set of the $2^n$ possible values of $x^n$. The distortion of a code is defined as being $\mathbb{E}[d(X^n , \phi(X^n)]$ where $\phi(\cdot) = g_n(f_n(\cdot))$. Here, $f_n(\cdot)$ is the encoder and $g_n(\cdot)$ is the decoder.

Comment: Thank you, boss @KillaKem. Makes sense